# Include in nunjucks (grunt-nunjucks-2-html) are based on an incorrect path

Tags: javascript, node.js, include, gruntjs, nunjucks

I'm using Nunjucks with grunt/node via the grunt plugin *grunt-nunjucks-2-html*

My root path is where the gruntfile is, so it's look like this:

```
./src
    index.html
    expo.html
    ./inc
        head.html
        header.html
```

My gruntfile config looks like this :

```
nunjucks: {
    render: {
        files: [
            {
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'src/',
                src: "*.html",
                dest: pathbuild,
                ext: ".html"
            }
        ]
    }
},
```

in my *index.html* I have this:

```
{% include "inc/head.html" %}
```

When I try `grunt nunjucks`, this is what I get

```
Warning: (unknown path) Error: template not found: inc/head.html
Use --force to continue.
```

That can be solved if I change path to `"src/inc/head/html"` but I don't get why I need to specified this, seems not logical to me.

Do you have something to teach to me that I've missed so hard?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and after looking at the plugin code, I noticed that the template path had to be supplied as an array:

```
nunjucks: {
  options: {
    paths: ['templates'], // 'templates' as a string can now be passed (30Oct2014)
    data: grunt.file.readJSON('results.json')
  },
  render: {
    files: [
       {
          expand: true,
          cwd: "templates/",
          src: "*.html",
          dest: "build/",
          ext: ".html"
       }
    ]
  }
}
```

I've sent a pull request (https://github.com/vitkarpov/grunt-nunjucks-2-html/pull/4) so if it gets accepted, we'll be able to supply the template path as a string.

Update 30-Oct-14: The pull request has been merged, so a string or array can be passed to options.paths.